# C# EventHandler Question

Tags: c#, methods, event-handling

Quick question regarding EventHandlers in C#, let's say we have the following code:

```
MyObject.MyEventHandler += (...)
```

I am currently refactoring some code, and the (...) is often replaced with another eventhandler, as such :

```
EventHandler A;

Test()
{    
   A += A_Method;
   MyObject.MyEventHandler += A       
}
```

Wouldn't it be simpler to disregard "A" and just write instead:

```
Test()
{    
   MyObject.MyEventHandler += A_Method;       
}
```

What is the use of EventHandler "A", if we can just directly pass the method to the EventHandler object from "MyObject" ?

Thanks !

Comment: substituted, replaced, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean

```
A += A_Method;
MyObject.MyEventHandler += A;
```

(without parentheses after A_Method).  If so, assuming that there is nothing more complex around this than the example, `A` can probably be safely omitted.  When refactoring, F12 (go to definition) is your friend: find all references and make sure they all are properly re-routed, etc.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake on my part, the parentheses shouldn't be there. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Sure, as long as `A` isn't used other places.  Otherwise it might have been a refactoring to reduce code duplication.

Comment: Actually "A" is only used in two instances, when subscribing to "MyEventHandler" and when unsubscribing from it, which is why I didn't find any use to it. Could you give an example as to when declaring the EventHandler A would be useful ? Thanks

Comment: I can't think of one, but I'm sure Jon Skeet could come up with something.  If you say his name three times he'll show up.